# Why does the add user function not work in pyftpdlib

Tags: python, server, ftp, pyftpdlib

I am making a web server using pyftpdlib but for some reason the `add_user()` function does not work and gives me an error
code:

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PATH = 'C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/My code/Camera/Recordings'
os.chdir(PATH)

addr = (ip,21)
authorizer = DummyAuthorizer
authorizer.add_user('admin','adminpass','.',perm='elradfmw')

handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
server = FTPServer(addr,handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

error:

````
  File "C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/My code/Camera/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    authorizer.add_user('admin','adminpass','.',perm='elradfmw')
TypeError: add_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'homedir'```
````

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: `authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()` – You are missing the brackets.

Comment: Did adding the brackets help?